# Serve node Webapp on port 80 in amazon ec2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I have a node application listening on port 80, I have set the security groups open on port 80.
[image]

But, when I access my webapp in browser via public ip(http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/), it doesn't show up.

What could be the issue?

I've use this doc as a guide https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-http-https-ec2/

Comment: Check your subnet is public or private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your security group already allowed traffic It means something wrong with the instance.

The first step to debug such an issue to verify the application status inside the instance.

- do `ssh` to the instance and verify is the instance responding on localhost `curl localhost`
- check is the process running, if you are using any nodejs process manager like pm2 `pm2 list` or forever `forever list` or `ps -aux | grep node`
- Verify is the server running on port `80`.
- check is the port occupied `netstat -antu | grep LISTEN`

In short, if the application responding on localhost using `curl localhost`, then as mentioned in the comment then the instance is in the private subnet.

you can check this [article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario2.html) to know about public and private subnet.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction. curl localhost failed on the connection. any suggestions on how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Verify the port, is the port 80 correct ot verify the application is running or not

Answer (score 0):

So The answer was, my security groups were fine. My app wasn't running because I didn't set the environment variable correctly. sudo PORT=80 node server.js was the command I needed.